# Why does React/webpack pad evaluation of JS expressions with unnecessary comments in html when server-side rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I've noticed that when I use curly braces to evaluate JS expressions within React, the result of that expression will be padded with unnecessary comments. For example, putting the following within the render function of a component, where test="Hello":

```
<p> {test} World</p>
```

will yield the following in the html:

```
<p>
  Hello
  <!-- --> 
  World
</p>
```

These unnecessary comments seem to only happen when using the curly braces to evaluate a JS expression and appear to be separating the dynamic text (the result of the evaluated expression - 'Hello') from the static text ('World').

Does anyone knows why this happens and what purpose it serves? Is this something that can be prevented without altering my code (maybe through the webpack configuration or minimizing my bundle)?

**UPDATE:** I realized that some of the comments said that they couldn't reproduce the error, which made me realize that the fact that I am server-side rendering could play into the issue (which it does!). I tested with a client side rendering application and this does not happen, but it does when server-side rendering.

Comment: FWIW, I [couldn't reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/wwypyx49ll) the empty comments.

Comment: Can you post your webpack config? That looks like some sort of a plugin issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding! It seems this error is exclusive to server-rendering. Sorry for the confusion!